# DeviceEventEmitter it's been listening twice

Tags: react-native

I don't know why when I fire an event the **DeviceEventEmitter.addListener** it's been emit once but listening twice.

I have a component **Base** that it's been add in every screen, something like

```
<View>
    {this.props.children}
    <ModalComponent />
</View>
```

Where the **ModalComponent** should be able to open anytime that **ModalVisible** event it's fired.

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('ModalVisible', this.onModalVisible)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('ModalVisible', this.onModalVisible)
  }

  onModalVisible = (args) => {
    console.log(['ModalVisible', args]) // logging twice
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: args.visible
    })
  }

  close () {
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: false
    })
  }

  onRequestClose = () => {
    this.close()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal animationType={'slide'} transparent={false} visible={this.state.modalVisible} onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose}>
        ...
      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

And I have a Server the emits the event when needed

```
  static show (data) {
    console.log(['Service.show', data]) // only once
    DeviceEventEmitter.emit('ModalVisible', { visible: true })
  }
```

When Service.show it's called, the first log appears only once, but right away at the **addListener** it's been logged twice.

I've already tried

```
this.listener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(...)
this.listener.remove()
```

and

```
this.onModalVisible.bind(this)
```

But it gave me every the same problem.

Besides that, at the same moment the Modal it's been duplicated, where when I close, I have two modals to be close.

I also tried load all this in a new screen, without parents components, to see if that could be the problem, mas no. It still.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems with events being fired/registered twice with socket.io, my problem was due to the fact that I was adding eventListeners on DidMount method. But since my component was mounted multiple it was also adding eventListeners multiple times.

My guess is that you are using the same component multiple times and so adding multiple times the same eventListener. Try to add your eventsListener into another place that will be called only once.

Comment: Worked! but... it's the same logic of Base component. Modal it's inside Base and Base exists only once at the screens. So WTH?

Comment: @kittu88, I was using `react-navigation` and the issue was because I had two Navigator, `StackNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator`; So I start to use only `DrawerNavigator`.

Comment: Glad it worked, I think the best thing to do is to centralize your events creation somewhere in your app, like on the DidMount of your root component to ensure that it gets not registered more than once, also you can leverage the `hasListeners('eventName')` to check how many listener are registered and clean it if there are more than one

Answer (score 1):

today, I met the problem too. and I look at the source js. I find the `DeviceEventEmit.addListener` will actually call `EventSubscriptionVendor.addSubscription method`.

```
_subscriber: EventSubscriptionVendor;
addListener(
    eventType: string,
    listener: Function,
    context: ?Object,
  ): EmitterSubscription {
    return (this._subscriber.addSubscription(
      eventType,
      new EmitterSubscription(this, this._subscriber, listener, context),
    ): any);
  }

 addSubscription(
    eventType: string,
    subscription: EventSubscription,
  ): EventSubscription {
    invariant(
      subscription.subscriber === this,
      'The subscriber of the subscription is incorrectly set.',
    );
    if (!this._subscriptionsForType[eventType]) {
      this._subscriptionsForType[eventType] = [];
    }
    const key = this._subscriptionsForType[eventType].length;
//here is the point
this._subscriptionsForType[eventType].push(subscription);
    subscription.eventType = eventType;
    subscription.key = key;
    return subscription;
  }
```

in the inner method, it will push the listener's argus function into an array; when we call it many times, it will push many listeners' function.

so in the project, we have to avoid call it many times, and after the component unmount, we have to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the "DeviceEventEmitter.addListener" with useEffect:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386913/7126848

Answer (score 0):

****_reactnative.deviceeventemitter.remotelistener is not a function in react native****

- when I upgrade the React Native version from 0.66 to 0.73, it mostly arises because most dependencies need to be upgraded individually inside the component where it is created. When I want to show it show then i upgrade some dependencies inside the component. Finally, the issue is solved.