# React navigation event listeners being called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement some listeners on react navigation using a functional component approach:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {

  const [subs, setSubs] = React.useState([]); 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSubs([
      navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => console.log('will focus')),
      navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => console.log('will blur')),
      navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => console.log('did focus')),
      navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => console.log('did blur')),
    ]);

    return () => {
      setSubs([]) 
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    ...
  )
};
```

Following the advice: https://fantashit.com/navigation-listeners-firing-multiple-times-per-event/

However what seems to be happening is each listener is being called twice, and I'm unsure how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener) say:

> addListener returns a function that can be called to unsubscribe from the event.

Try cleaning up each subscription in cleanup function:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unSubs = [
    navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => console.log('will focus')),
    navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => console.log('will blur')),
    navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => console.log('did focus')),
    navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => console.log('did blur')),
  ]

  return function cleanup() {
    unSubs.forEach((unSub) => {
      unSub()
    })
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 9):

It is fact for react native, whenever you add listeners for any mounted screen, the **listeners are still active after screen is unmounted**. And whenever such listeners try to change state of an unmounted screen, react native will generate warning.
so always try to add listeners whenever you mount screen and remove the same while unmounting

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {

  const [subs, setSubs] = React.useState([]); 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSubs([
      navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => console.log('will focus')),
      navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => console.log('will blur')),
      navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => console.log('did focus')),
      navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => console.log('did blur')),
    ]);

    const unsubscribe = () =>{
    navigation.removeAllListeners();
    }
    // Remove all listeners, because there have to be no listeners on unmounted screen
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [])
```

same can be achieved by the following in react navigation

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() =>{

      // Listening on the refresh event
       RefreshEventEmitter.addListener("refresh", () => {
         console.log("Refresh event emitted");
       });

      // ----------------------------------------------
      // Removing all the listeners, so that screen does not re-render after unmounting..
      const unsubscribe = () => {
        RefreshEventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
      };

 
      // Returned function is called when screen is unmounted from display!!
      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [])
  );
```

useFocusEffect is called once when screen is mounted to the display and returned function by the same is called when screen is unmounted from the display.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the "DeviceEventEmitter.addListener" with useEffect:

1: `import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";`

2: Set no of counts you want to show the event:

`const [buttonSyncEnabled, setButtonSyncEnabled] = useState(false);`

3: Finally wrap the event with useEffect :

```
useEffect( () =>{
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('syncEvent',
(e)=>{
  console.log("NATIVE_EVENT");
  console.log(e);
  if(e === 'syncEnableEventData'){
    handleButtonSyncEnable();
    setCount(1);
  }
  if(e === 'syncDisableEventData'){
    handleButtonSyncDisable();
    setCount(1);
  }
  
  })


}, []);
```